# Problems with simple c task

Tags: c

So after a few years of inactivity after studying at uni, I'm trying to build up my c experience with a simple string reverser.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*
* 
*/
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
reverser();
return(0);
}

int reverser(){
printf("Please enter a String: ");
//return (0);
int len;
char input[10];
scanf("%s",&input);
int quit = strcmp(input,"quit");
if(quit == 0){
    printf("%s\n","Program quitting");
    return(0);
}



len = strlen(input);
printf("%i\n",len);

char reversed[len];

int count = 0;

while (count <= (len-1)){
    //printf("%i\n",(len-count));
 reversed[count] = input[(len-1)-count];   
 count++;
}


//printf("%s\n",input);
printf(reversed); 
printf("\n");
reverser();


}
```

When I input "hello", you would expect "olleh" as the response, but I get "olleh:$a ca&@",

How do I just get the string input reversed and returned?

Bombalur

Comment: did you add a terminating null to the end of the reversed string? i.e. '\0'?

Comment: You're forgetting that strings terminate with a zero byte. You need to add that zero after the last character in `reversed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are conventionally terminated by a zero byte. So it should be

```
char reversed[len+1];
```

And you should clear the last byte

```
reversed[len] = (char)0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a '\0' at the end of the array. (as in, copy only chars until you reach '\0' - which is the point at array[strlen(array)], then when you're done, add a '\0' at the next character)

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the `\0` at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating an array with size 10. When you take in some data into it (using scanf) and the array is not filled up completely, the printf from this array will give junk values in the memory. You should iterate for the length of the input by checking \n.

Answer (score 0):

must have a size + 1 to string length so that you can have a \0  at the end of string that will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The following is a (simple and minimal implementation of) string reverse program (obviously, error conditions, corner cases, blank spaces, wider character sets, etc has not been considered).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strlen(char *s)
{
    char *p = s;
    while (*p)
        p++;
    return p - s;
}

char * strrev(char a[])
{
    int i, j;
    char temp;

    for (i=0, j=strlen(a)-1 ; i<j ; i++, j--) {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
        }

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    printf("The reverse is %s \n", strrev(str));

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!